# Pass functions variable to another function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function

I am getting a JSON object using `XMLHttpRequest`. I have to call parameter `applicationContent` from `applicationData()` function in window load event.

This is my JSON file:

```
{
  "content": {
    "siteCat": {
      "copy$$udo_template": {
        "domain": "host",
        "page_load": 5,
        "pageName": "Testing"
      },
      "copy$$dashboard_template": {
        "domain": "host",
        "content_ID": 5,
        "pageName": "dashboard"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is my JavaScript:

```
var dataCall = function() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4) {
        if (this.status == 200) {
          resolve(this.responseText);
        } else {
          console.log(this.status + '.....' + this.statusText)
        }
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:4200/assets/sample.json", true);
    xhttp.send();
  })
}

dataCall().then((CallResponse) => {
  getData(CallResponse)

});

var getData = function(cData) {
  jsonResponse = cData.replace(/'/g, '"');
  parsedJsonResponse = JSON.parse(this.jsonResponse);
  var appData = parsedJsonResponse['content']['siteCat']['copy$$udo_template'];
  console.log(parsedJsonResponse);
}
```

In `applicationData()` function I'm getting the JSON data I want.

```
function applicationData = function(applicationContent) {
  var appData = parsedJsonResponse['content']['siteCat']['copy$$' + applicationContent];
  console.log(appData);
}
```

I need to call same `appData` in `window.load` function without a `return` statement in `appData`. Because after `appData` variable I am making changes to the data I'm receiving. Is it possible to get the first line of `applicationData`?

And here in `window.load` function I should receive `"copy$$dashboard_template"`key.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
  applicationData();
  var x = appData;
  console.log(x)
})
```

Comment: Why do you not want to 'return' from your function applicationData?

Comment: Whats stopping you from returning the data in `applicationData` and then calling it again after you make changes to the data?

Comment: @Wamadahama, @Jhony,  once I returned it gives me the updated data of `appData` variable. Is there a way I can get it before it is getting updated.

Comment: get another argument in applicationData function, that is a function you wish to call(it would be everything you want to do), and call it in applicationData wherever you want. but don't forget to attach applicationData context to your new-written function, so call it like this: `myNewFunction.call(this, any, other, parameters, ...) `